# Notify-send not working when run from apache

Tags: x11, php, notifications

I have the following script (`alert.sh)` which has been setuid'd:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 notify-send --urgency=low -i python "The job has finished"
```

and the following PHP file `alert.php`:

```
<?php
echo exec("/path/to/alert.sh")
```

When I `su` to `www-data` and run `php alert.php`, I get an alert on my screen. All good.

However, when I open `alert.php` in the browser, nothing happens.

I suspect some environment variable needs to be set, but I'm not sure which.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out while digging through the environment variables, I also have to set `$XAUTHORITY` to whatever the variable is in the normal login.

```
XAUTHORITY=/home/myusername/.Xauthority DISPLAY=:0.0 notify-send --urgency=low -i python "The job has finished"
```